# Perform an Operation when Registering to an Event?

Tags: c#, events

I was wandering is it possible to start a timer or perform an operation when you register to an event (from the events POV)?  In other words I have an event that gets triggered on a timer, however I only want the Timer to start when a function registers to this specific event, thus if the user never registers to the event the timer never start. And conversely when the user unregisters from the event and it is the last registered function the time stops.
Thanks

Comment: I was able to understand the first part. But, in the unregister event case, can you elaborate? "it is the last registered function the time stops." is not clear for me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply need to implement the add and remove accessors for the event. Generally they are implied, but you can explicitly implement them.

```
public event EventHandler MyEvent
{
  add
  {
    // start timer
  }

  remove
  {
     // stop timer
  }
```

The link below has a tutorial about it.

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-event-accessors&ei=ZYGtUMWOCPGFyQHU84H4Ag&usg=AFQjCNE5RG2taqNrJROy6P6Jpog3UNkvzQ

Comment: Note that when you do this you are completely *replacing* the add/remove methods, not executing that code *in addition to* the add/remove methods, so you'll also need to manually store the event handlers in the add method and remove them in the remove method.